# Left floated elements out of alignment

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have coded the head banner and the containers for the news below the header. Now I'm trying to make my left menus, but this happens:

[image: Screenshot]

Instead of going against the header and the news containers, they are going they go over them.

HTML Code:

```
<div style="width: 269px;">
<h1 style="text-align:left;">Newsletter</h1>
<div id="newsletter"></div>
<h1 style="text-align:left;">Prizes</h1>
<div id="prizes"></div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#prizes {
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/vv8Czrb.png");
float:left;
width: 269px;
height: 136px;
}

#newsletter {
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/2sV7lc9.png");
float:left;
width: 269px;
height: 284px;
}
```

#### Everything I have so far

```css
#container {
  padding-left: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
p {
  display: inline block;
  width: 261px;
  height: 155px;
}
#left {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/3rpQxq8.png");
  float: left;
  width: 261px;
  height: 154px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}
#left:hover,
#right:hover,
#center:hover {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/igiLhj9.png");
  z-index: 82;
}
#left-readmore:hover,
#right-readmore:hover,
#center-readmore:hover {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/l5UpJa5.png");
}
#left-readmore p,
#right-readmore p,
#center-readmore p {
  padding-top: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
#right {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/3rpQxq8.png");
  float: right;
  width: 261px;
  height: 154px;
  margin-right: 90px;
}
#center {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/3rpQxq8.png");
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 261px;
  height: 154px;
}
#left-txtcontainer {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/3vF32is.png");
  float: left;
  width: 261px;
  height: 155px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}
#right-txtcontainer {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/3vF32is.png");
  float: right;
  width: 261px;
  height: 155px;
  margin-right: 90px;
}
#center-txtcontainer {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/3vF32is.png");
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 261px;
  height: 155px;
}
#left-readmore {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/iIJbqsY.png");
  float: left;
  width: 262px;
  height: 26px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}
#right-readmore {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/iIJbqsY.png");
  float: right;
  width: 262px;
  height: 26px;
  margin-right: 90px;
}
#center-readmore {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/iIJbqsY.png");
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 262px;
  height: 26px;
}
#head-banner {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/z1YxsTp.png");
  width: 820px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 290px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#prizes {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/vv8Czrb.png");
  float: left;
  width: 269px;
  height: 136px;
}
#newsletter {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/2sV7lc9.png");
  float: left;
  width: 269px;
  height: 284px;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;width: 269px;">
  <h1 style="text-align:left;">Newsletter</h1>
  <div id="newsletter"></div>
  <h1 style="text-align:left;">Prizes</h1>
  <div id="prizes"></div>
  <br clear="all" />
</div>

<div id="head-banner"></div>

<br style="clear:both;">

<div id="container">

  <div id="left">
    <img style="padding-top: 6px; padding-left: 6px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/cJL1FCx.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <img style="padding-top: 6px; padding-left: 6px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/cJL1FCx.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <img style="padding-top: 6px; padding-left: 6px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/cJL1FCx.png"></img>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="left-txtcontainer">
    <p>
      Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem
      iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="right-txtcontainer">
    <p>
      Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem
      iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="center-txtcontainer">
    <p>
      Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem
      iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-readmore">
    <p>Read more...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right-readmore">
    <p>Read more...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="center-readmore">
    <p>Read more...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <img style="padding-top: 6px; padding-left: 6px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/cJL1FCx.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <img style="padding-top: 6px; padding-left: 6px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/cJL1FCx.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <img style="padding-top: 6px; padding-left: 6px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/cJL1FCx.png"></img>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="left-txtcontainer">
    <p>
      Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem
      iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="right-txtcontainer">
    <p>
      Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem
      iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="center-txtcontainer">
    <p>
      Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem
      iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.Lorem iposum sample text.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-readmore">
    <p>Read more...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right-readmore">
    <p>Read more...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="center-readmore">
    <p>Read more...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using float with your CSS, make sure to clear the structure as well. Here is an example using old code (pre 2010) to understand:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">Left Menu</div>
    <div id="right">Right Body Content</div>
    <br clear="all" />
</div>
```

And here is a JSFiddle you can start to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/qqLry5tn/

Many frameworks nowadays (bootstrap, grid layouts, etc.) normally add the clearing to the container tag to remove the need for the extra

Here is a good article that explains why we need to clear: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Hope this helps!